# Can't resolve 'electron' in '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/swarm-js/node_modules/got'

Tags: nft, swarm

Repo: https://github.com/vortextemporum/BoringBananasCompany

I added Infura node provider to the `config.js`

Deploying to Netlify using

`yarn build`

build dir: `build`

It works fine off my ubuntu 20.04 lts on wsl2 using localhost:3000 using `yarn start` or even localhost:5000 using `yarn build`, but for whatever reason, Netlify throws an error during runtime.

```
6:52:01 PM: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'electron' in '/opt/build/repo/node_modules/swarm-js/node_modules/got'
6:52:01 PM: > Build error occurred
6:52:01 PM: Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
6:52:01 PM:     at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:15:924
6:52:01 PM:     at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:6:584)
6:52:01 PM: error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Duplicate of a question asked here (with the solution): https://stackoverflow.com/a/70082382

Answer (score 0):

Recommend deleting the node modules folder. Build it again. it should resolve the error. It did for me. Hope it works.

Comment: So, how would that work exactly. If the .gitignore ignores uploading node_modules. Then Netlify would be deploying fresh node_modules every time a deploy is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same issue. Netlify build fails whenever I import web3 into a NextJS page, ex:

```
import Web3 from "web3"
```

Getting that same error - 'Can't resolve 'electron'.

I'm guessing this has something to do with server vs client side rendering and web3 probably doesn't work with server side, which may be the default for Next. I am new to both Next and web3 though so this is taking me some time to figure out. Thanks.

Comment: agree with this, did you find the solution? I also get same issue I also have web3 imported